# Azure create VM from existing disk using the new portal

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

How do you create a vm from an existing disk with the new portal (not the classic portal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a little time thinking 'this has got to be possible' then spending some more time poking around in the Portal to try to figure out how. I've come to the conclusion that this isn't possible.

I concede that this is simply from poking around trying to find a way to do this, so I may have missed it.

I imagine this will change in future, it has got to be on a plan somewhere! But at the time of writing this, the only way of starting a v2 VM is programmatically, i.e. Powershell, .Net, REST or through JSON Templates.

Obviously classic mode VMs (v1) can be created through the old portal.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a trick to create an Azure VM from an existing disk (using the image file .vhd), you had to:

1. Create a **DevTest Labs** item
2. Go to Configuration -> Custom Images
3. Add a new images (vhd) following the istruction
4. Then you will be able to create (always in your DevTest Labs item) a new VM from the custom image that you had uploaded.

[source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-lab/devtest-lab-create-template)